# how to say "projected numbers" in chinese (mandarin)?

Tags: translation

appreciate if someone can let me know how to translate the following into mandarin, thanks!

"kindly provide me with the full year numbers up to october, we will use it to project for the full 12 months."

Comment: If your number is money, 预算（budget）

Comment: not really, it's the amount of water consumed and waste disposed...

Comment: @chsword 预算 is not projected numbers, but more of a planning. Like budget in English may but may not be related to past spending.

Comment: 如能供应请给我提供整年直到１０月的数字，我们用它来预计整整１２个月（although grammars say:＂它＂很少作宾语，readers come across such use all the time, see jukuu)

Comment: This cannot be directly translated. We need to fully understand what the "numbers" are for. Amount of consumed water and waste disposed? What type of waste? waste water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"we will use it to project for the full 12 months => "我們會用來**推算**全年的數字".

Answer (score 1):

First, translate to English:

"kindly provide me with the full year numbers up to october, we will use it to project for the full 12 months."

Please provide me with the figures for this year up to October, we will then use that to estimate the values for the whole year.

Given that, it can't be toooo hard to translate， though my Chinese is none too hot.

Please provide me with the figures for this year up to October,
请提供今年到十月的数据，

we will then use that to estimate the values for the whole year.
然后我们会用这些数据来估计整年的使用。

Something along those lines.